# My select distinct query within oledb is only ever returning one row. Why is it doing this

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I'm trying to grab the total unique entries within an excel column for part of a progress bar inside of my windows forms gui. Yet, when I call the below function, it only ever returns a single row. I'm using worksheet.rows.count to find the total unique 'Procedure ID' entries.

```
public static int procedureTotals(string excelFile) {
        string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFile
                            + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;'";
        string sql = null;
        string worksheetName = null;

        DataTable schema = null;
        DataTable worksheet = null;
        DataSet workbook = new DataSet();
        OleDbConnection objconn = new OleDbConnection(connection);
        objconn.Open();
        schema = objconn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        worksheetName = schema.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
        sql = "SELECT DISTINCT 'Procedure ID' FROM[" + worksheetName + "]";// GROUP BY 'Procedure ID'";
        //data adapter
        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        objAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, objconn);
        objAdapter.Fill(workbook);
        worksheet = workbook.Tables[0];
        objconn.Close();

        return worksheet.Rows.Count;
    }
```

Comment: And you are **200% sure** there should be more than 1 row here?

Comment: You need to perform your SELECT on a cell range, not a worksheet.  There's only **one** worksheet.

Comment: Yes marc, there are roughly 55000 entries in the excel document. Robert, how do I to i specify the cell range? It's in column[0] if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT 'Procedure ID' FROM[" + worksheetName + "]";
```

Here you are retrieving only one column of data. Please update the query to

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [" + worksheetName + "]";
```

and try this out..:)

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting the column header so it returns one record "Producer ID" since you put quotes around it as if it were a  string.

you are going to have to change your column name to a none spaced word (Procedure_ID) so you don't need to single quotes. when you use single quotes the system thinks you are trying to include the header in your search and returns only one row >> the header.

I hope I explained that correct.